# Rails 4 - Accessing stylesheet in public folder from another domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a css file in my public/assets/stylesheets/example.css directory. How can I access this css file directly from a url?

Ive tried www.app.com/assets/stylesheets/example.css but it doesnt work. I thought the public folder was the default folder in production? Im running rails 4 with passenger in a dedicated server (not heroku).

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you use assets procompilation you need to append the cacheing hash to the end of the filename (e.g. : application-03ed2f1b0877b3bc13330388bee8d3f0.css ) in addition, even if your project has more than one css, in production they will all end up into the same application-[...].css file. One option, other than updating the url every time you update your css, is to make a symlink to the css:

```
ln -s /var/www/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/example.css /var/www/myapp/app/public/assets/external-example.css
```

EDIT: 
also the url would be:
http://example.com/assets/application.css 
not
http://example.com/assets/stylesheets/application.css